# Confusion about proof in "Representation Learning with Contrastive Predictive Coding"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mutual-information

In the Appendix A.1 of the paper "[Representation Learning with Contrastive Predictive Coding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03748)", the author prove $\log N-\mathcal L_N$ is the lower bound of mutual information between $x_{t+k}$ and $c_t$, $I(x_{t+k}, c_t)$, where and $N$ is the number of sample(one positive sample $x_{t+k}$ and N-1 negative samples $x_j\in X_{neg}$) and $\mathcal L_N$ is roughly the noise contrastive estimation loss defined as
$$
\mathcal L_N=-\mathbb E_X\left[\log {f_k(x_{t+k}|c_t)\over\sum_{x_j\in X}f_k(x_j|c_t)}\right]\\
where\quad f_k(x_{t+k},c_t)\propto{p(x_{t+k}|c_t)\over p(x_{t+k})}
$$
Here is the proof they provide
[image]

I'm confused about Equation 9: why is $E_{x_j}{p(x_j|c_t)\over p(x_j)}$ equal to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $\nu$ be the dominating measure of these densities (and assuming it's the same), we'll have
$$
E_{x_j}\left(\frac{p(x_j\mid c_t)}{p(x_j)}\right) = \int \frac{p(x_j\mid c_t)}{p(x_j)} p(x_j)\,\text d\nu(x_j) \\
= \int p(x_j\mid c_t)\,\text d\nu(x_j) = 1.
$$
We don't have to worry about $0/0$ issues since that happens on areas with zero probability under $p(x_j)$.